# how to mirror a whole database cluster in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, mirror

I'm using a postgresql (9.6) database in my project which is currently in development stage.

For production I want to use an exact copy/mirror of the database-cluster with a slightly different name.

I am aware of the fact that I can make a backup and restore it under a different cluster-name, but is there something like a mirror function via the psql client or pgAdmin (v.4) that mirrors all my schemas and tables and puts it in a new clustername?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you can use any existing database (which needs to be idle in order for this to work) on the server as a template when you want to create a new database with that content. You can use the following SQL statement:

```
CREATE DATABASE newdb WITH TEMPLATE someDbName OWNER dbuser;
```

But you need to make sure no user is currently connected or using that database - otherwise you will get following error.

```
ERROR:  source database "someDbName" is being accessed by other users
```

Hope that helped ;)